# Convert libvirt Xen configuration to native

Tags: configuration, xen, libvirt, conversion

I've configured some virtual machine under Xen on Debian Squeeze using libvirt with virsh.
Now I want to get rid of the libvirt layer, because I need to configure some specific parameters on the DomUs that are not supported by libvirt.

1. How can I export my config ?
2. How can I import the native config file to Xen ?

Thank you for any suggestion !

Comment: How does the current configuration look like? Can you post it?

Comment: What do you want to know ?
I use
  sudo virsh list
to list domaind
and
  sudo virsh edit vmname
to edit DomUs configuration.
I want to export libvirt xml config, uninstall libvirt, and after convert xml xonfig to native Xen and use it.
Please ask whatever you want to know.

Comment: I don`t know how a libvirt config looks like, but I know that xen understands XML format quite well. So post your libvirt xml config here. I suspect you can use it with XEN right away (btw - which xen version?)

Answer (score 2):

You would export the xml config and then convert it to XEN Configs:

```
virsh -c xen:/// domxml-to-native xen-xm rhel5pv.xml
```

http://libvirt.org/drvxen.html#xmlexport

Answer (score 2):

An update: Newer versions of Xen have [a new toolstack](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Choice_of_Toolstacks): xen-light, so from xen 4.1 onwards the `xm` command is superceded by `xl`.

While `xl`'s domain configuration files are backwards compatible, to make sure all domain parameters are correctly mapped into the latest configuration during conversion I would suggest to use:

```
virsh -c xen:/// domxml-to-native --format xen-xl \
    /path/to/libvirt/vm.domxml.cfg > vm.xenxl.cfg
```

(note the use of `xen-xl` instead of `xen-xm`).

Then, you can create the vm directly on Xen using the generated file:

```
xl create -f vm.xenxl.cfg
```

(Documenting it here, as the `virsh` [command reference](http://libvirt.org/virshcmdref.html) section for `domxml-to-native` says "Options: Needs to be written")

Answer (score 0):

If u just want to edit domU's configuration, try below,

`virsh edit vm-name`

It will use vi to open xml by default